# Vue filter array item with dots causing issue (vue bootstrap table)

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/ and have setup a search for each header. I have this filter:

```
filtered() {
      console.log(this.filters);
      const filtered = this.person.filter(item => {
        return Object.keys(this.filters).every(key =>
          String(item[key])
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.filters[key].toLowerCase())
        );
      });
      return filtered.length > 0
        ? filtered
        : [
            {
              name: "",
              "comments.value": "",
              "interests.sport.football": "",
            }
          ];
    }
```

but noticed I probably can adapt the search from the example here https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example but the problem is if the field I am using is not on the first level in the object the individual search on a field does not work. I.e. in json file like this:

```
{
  "interests": {
    "sport": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Football",
    }
  },
  "name": "Jerry"
},
{
  "interests": {
    "sport": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Golf",
    }
  },
  "name": "Jeff"
}
```

name would work but if I wanted to search interests.sport.name it would not work. In the data for fields it works to identify the field from the json as interests.sport.name but not to search against? I assume it's something to do with the dots?

**Data**:

```
filters: {
  interests: "",
  name: ""
}
```

Comment: The default filter function seems to work fine for this, for example: https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/pooYqvo?editors=1010. Can you provide an example of the problem?

Comment: ah now I use a slot for the fields that allows the search all in one go to work, if I try and search individual fields  using the radio boxes or with the above filter I get an error

Comment: You can filter for specific fields as shown [here](https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/pooYqvo?editors=1010), but you need to specify a top level field (and that is all that will work) - so for the sport name, that would be `interests` alone. That works in my simplistic example at least, otherwise you'll have to go with a computed property and custom filter function.

Comment: ah cool, thanks, that's a great help

Comment: One last thing, I've added what the data is for my filters computed method, is there a reason why this would not be able to search the the object? I get a blank result if I try to on interests but works on name

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, please provide a repro

Comment: ah ok yes, sorry https://codepen.io/street_spirit/pen/dyyLVqx?editors=1010